# Wifi Direct P2P-go and P2P-client support in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, kernel, wifi-direct

I am trying to get wifi direct working on a laptop with ubuntu 12.04

When I type the command 'iw list' it doesn't show P2P-client or P2P-go under 'supported interface modes.From http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw/replace-iwconfig I found that 'iwconfig' was replaced with 'iw'.Does it mean that my hardware doesn't have support for wifi-direct or is it just the software(drivers) issue? If is it just sofware issue please help me to find the right drivers which support wifi-direct.

Here is the info about my ethernet controller from the output of 'lspci'

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communication Inc. AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)     
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8055 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the FAQ http://www.wi-fi.org/knowledge-center/faq/will-legacy-devices-be-upgradeable-support-specification-underlying-wi-fi which states that wifi-direct does not require any new hardware.For drivers check http://madwifi-project.org/. Fo atheros, ath9k drivers support wifi direct.

Comment: Can you please confirm if ath9k drivers support my network adapter? Because I didn't find AR242x listed under supported chipset in the page http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k.

Comment: I have figured out that I can't use ath9k drivers for my wireless adapter and also that wifi direct needs 802.11n support which my wireless card doesn't have and hence gave up my attempt to get wifi direct working on my laptop.